# React Native using Expo changed logged in user suddenly

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm building a small social media app using React Native, Expo, Redux and firebase.

I created multiple user accounts for testing, i logged in the app using one of them, while i was working on the app, it suddenly changed the user account I logged in with to another user!

Is it normal? If not, what would be the reason for that??

Here's how the registration is being handled:

```
export class Register extends Component {
 constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        email: '',
        password: '',
        name: '', 
        lastname: '',
        degree: '',
        description:''
         }

    this.onSignUp = this.onSignUp.bind(this)
       }


onSignUp(){

if(
    this.state.email != '' &&
    this.state.password != '' &&
    this.state.name != '' &&
    this.state.lastname != '' 
  ){
  const { email, password, name, lastname, degree, description } = 
    this.state;
    firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .then((result) => {
            firebase.firestore().collection("Doctors")
                .doc(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)
                .set({
                    name,
                    email,
                    lastname,
                    degree,
                    description
                })
            console.log(result)
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error)
        })
     }
   else{
    alert("Make sure you filled all the fields with correct info!");
 }
```

And Here's the App.js

```
export class App extends Component {
constructor(props) {
super(props)
this.state = {
  loaded: false,
  }
 }

  componentDidMount() {
   firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
    if (!user) {
      this.setState({
      loggedIn: false,
      loaded: true
    })
  } else {
    this.setState({
      loggedIn: true,
      loaded: true
    })
  }
})
 }
render() {

const { loggedIn, loaded } = this.state;
  if (!loaded) {
    return (
       <View></View>
        )
       }

if (!loggedIn) {
  return (
    <View></View>
  );
}

const onAuthStateChangedUnsubscribe = 
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(async (user) => {
  if (user) {
    // -> Alert Email Verification
    await user.sendEmailVerification()
    const onIdTokenChangedUnsubscribe = 
  firebase.auth().onIdTokenChanged((user) => {
      const unsubscribeSetInterval = setTimeout(() => {
        firebase.auth().currentUser.reload();
        firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken(/* forceRefresh */ true)
      }, 10000);

      if (user && user.emailVerified) {
        clearInterval(unsubscribeSetInterval) //delete interval
        onAuthStateChangedUnsubscribe() //unsubscribe onAuthStateChanged
        // -> Go to your screnn
        return onIdTokenChangedUnsubscribe() //unsubscribe 
  onIdTokenChanged
      }
    })
  }
})

return (
  <View></View>
   )
  }
 }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask - we cant anwser that question for you! Please edit the question and include some Code.

Comment: Not normal. Need more details on your setup and how your auth is SUPPOSED to work. Pay attention and report back specifically on how your authentication credentials and tokens are stored. Likely you're putting something in a static/global space that shouldn't be.

Comment: I updated the question with my registration page